# Name of relation between $p$ and $1 - p$ (for $0 \leq p \leq 1$)

Tags: terminology

We can say that $p$ is the *inverse* of $1/p$ and vice-versa.

Is there a similarly succinct phrase for $p$ and $1-p$ (assuming $p$ to be a real between 0 and 1)?

It would be akin to negation in probability, but that seems to be specific to probabilities. I'm rather wondering if there's a succinct phrase, for example, for the relation between the ratio of the journey completed and the ratio of the journey left.

Comment: **Complement** seems like a more likely term to employ in probability, but not on its own (where it applies to the event, not its probability). But in any event you'd have to clarify the meaning. I'm not aware of any specific term for this relationship.

Comment: Probably we can apply negation as failure to conclude that a general, widely-recognised and succinct term does not exist for this relation (which I find slightly surprising). Complement might be the closest we get.

Answer (score 1):

In probability, if p is the probability of success, then 1-p is the probability of failure. Often, this is denoted by q = 1-p, which can make binomial equations easier to work with. There may be a name for p versus q, but I don't know, other than the "difference from unity" perhaps.